# Can't hide object

Tags: rendering, animation, objects, outliner

I'm using a downloaded 3D model and can't hide an object from the render.

I want to hide Stormtrooper_Gun, when I try it it's like blocked and purple

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purple colour means that the object's render visibility is currently controlled by a driver. Right-click on the icon and select  <kbd>Delete Driver</kbd>.

Comment: It worked, thanks

Would you explain what's a driver please? I'm kinda new on this

Comment: See [Drivers — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html). Basically a way to control a value by another or a function. I reckon if you downloaded a rigged character, there probably is a controller somewhere in your rig that is specifically meant to enable/disable that object, I'd look into that if I were you, since it's often handier to use a rig's toggles than manually toggling objects on/off, and it's easier to animate too.

Comment: As @L0Lock says, read the manual. I understand that some third-party models are imported with drivers, presumably so that you can make the gun appear during an animation sequence.